# jquery - multi-step progress bar to show completed steps in Yii2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, yii2

How to make transition from one state to another as soon as order status gets change to new one. Im implementing this in Yii2.

```
    var i = 1;
$('.progress .circle').removeClass().addClass('circle');
$('.progress .bar').removeClass().addClass('bar');
setInterval(function() {
  $('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + i + ')').addClass('active');

  $('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + (i-1) + ')').removeClass('active').addClass('done');

  $('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + (i-1) + ') .label').html('&#10003;');

  $('.progress .bar:nth-of-type(' + (i-1) + ')').addClass('active');

  $('.progress .bar:nth-of-type(' + (i-2) + ')').removeClass('active').addClass('done');

  i++;

  if (i==0) {
    $('.progress .bar').removeClass().addClass('bar');
    $('.progress div.circle').removeClass().addClass('circle');
    i = 1;
  }
}, 1000);
```

Here is my JSfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/9cs776m0/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var circles = $('.progress .circle');
var currentCircle = circles.first();
var previousCircle = $();

(function()
{
    currentCircle.addClass('active');
    previousCircle.removeClass('active').addClass('done');

    var bar = currentCircle.prev();
    bar.addClass('done');

    previousCircle = currentCircle;
    currentCircle = currentCircle.nextAll('.circle:first');

    if (previousCircle.length)
    {
        setTimeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
    }
})();
```

I made it without additional class `half` on bar

http://jsfiddle.net/9cs776m0/2/

Comment: its not working, it should not change until next status gets updated. like amazon order status bar. when they change order status only then progress bar changes

Comment: @Saurabh you wrote it with setInterval, there is no button to trigger next status

Comment: Yes because I don't know how to write it can you please help me..?

Comment: can it link with database? as current status will store in database, bar will move according to status which is stored in database..

Comment: any example links if you can provide?

Comment: @Saurabh you need AJAX or WebSocket to stay connected with server

Comment: Yes its connected to database. im trying to display current status to the user. i'm done with status tracking, its showing current status when user search by its tracking id. when user search by its tracking id on the page it retrieving its name order id and current status like approved or dispatch. I just need to take the value of status from the page and use that value to show status graphically. how can I use status value from page to progress bar.?